# H/W Assisted Garbage Collector

Tags: java, garbage-collection, simulator

I was thinking of reducing the overhead  of garbage collectors in memory constrained systems, such as mobile device. By overhead I mean the pause time, or the fraction of total execution time spent in garbage collection. I came to know something about hardware assisted garbage collectors and I am interested in working on it.
I was wondering, what all has been done in this area.
And can I use simulator to estimate the efficiency of my garbage collector or I have to fabricate my design on chip?  Is there any simulator which can run java programs.

Comment: Try asking on http://cs.stackexchange.com/, the only real H/W assistance that is agreed on by everyone is being able to write (and maybe read) to ram bypassing the CPU cache.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [working approach to HW supported GC](http://www.azulsystems.com/blog/cliff/2008-11-18-brief-conversation-david-moon):

> Cliff Click wrote: Things we do specifically for Java:
>
> GC read-barrier enables a fully parallel & concurrent GC; we can sustain 40G/sec allocation on a 400G heap indefinitely, with max-pause times on the order of 10-20msec. This uber-GC is partially made possible because of the read barrier (and partially possible because we ‘own’ the OS and can play major page-mapping tricks).

and also

> The read-barrier will take a fast-trap on failure, and by default get promoted to GC-mode in the trap handler. This lets the faulting CPU fixup the object reference and continue, without needing to wait for GC to catch up.

Surely, the whole text is worth reading. You most probably want watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5uljtqyBLxI).

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering, what all has been done in this area.

If you go back to the 1980's, the Symbolics 3600 (aka Lisp Machine) had hardware support for tagged memory and write barriers.  There was also later academic work on topic. However, received wisdom is that special purpose hardware to support garbage collection is not cost effective [1] (page 221).

> And can I use simulator to estimate the efficiency of my garbage collector or I have to fabricate my design on chip?

I guess either approach would work (given enough effort), but both have issues that make them hard to "execute", and both leave open the issue of whether anything that you discover would be likely to be commercially viable.

Before you embark (seriously) on this topic, you should do a thorough review of previous research.  At least get hold of the books below, and locate and read the papers and articles on hardware gc support that they reference.

> Is there any simulator which can run java programs.

You are talking about a hardware simulator that would run program compiled to the simulated hardware's (hypothetical) instruction set.  Part of your project would be to implement a Java compiler backend to generate code in that instruction set.

Such a simulator + compiler *could* exist, but the chances are that it wouldn't be available to you.

References:

[1] "Garbage Collection: algorithms for automatic memory management" by R. Jones and R. Lins, Wiley 1996.

[2] "The Garbage Collection Handbook: The Art of Automatic Memory Management" by R. Jones, A. Hoskings and R. Moss.  Chapman and Hall, 2011.